# What was the purpose of the signs that Jesus did that were NOT written? John 20:30

Tags: john, jesus, miracle, sign

John 20:30 (ESV):

> 30 Now Jesus did **many other signs** in the presence of the disciples, **which are not written in this book**; 31 but these are written so that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that by believing you may have life in his name.

We are told that some signs that Jesus did were written so that *you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that by believing you may have life in his name*. But what about the signs that Jesus did that were NOT written? What were they for?

Comment: If we do not know what they are : how can we know their purpose ? It can only be a matter of opinion and speculation.

Comment: If Jesus did something that we needed to know about, it would have been recorded. It is most likely that additional signs he performed were similar to those he had already done. How many cases of blind eyes being opened do we need to read about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same vein, one might also ask about the inspired writing and sayings of various prophets that did not end up in the Bible such as:

- John the Baptist (Matt 11:9, Luke 7:26)
- Agabus (Acts 11;28, 21;10)
- Judas and Silas (Acts 15;32)
- Samuel (who is recorded as writing none of the OT)
- Nathan the prophet
- Gad the prophet

... and many more.  All these prophets, who did not contribute to the canon of Scripture, wrote and said things that were just as inspired by God but which did not become part of the Bible.  Presumably, their judgement, messages and writings (if they had any) were of a local nature and judged unsuitable for inclusion in the Bible.  Most of Paul's sermons are not included in the Bible.

The same is true of the many miracles that are not recorded in the Bible.  The Holy Spirit inspired the Bible writers to include what they did and the rest served some local purpose and were not included in the Bible, according to the sovereign choice of the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 0):

The context of your quoted passage helps with your question. That context is Thomas

> **JOHN 20:25** *So the other disciples told him, “We have seen the Lord!”
> But he said to them, “Unless I see the nail marks in his hands and put my finger where the nails were, and put my hand into his side, I will not believe.”*

Note - Thomas doubted - he needed to ‘see’ …. with his ‘natural eyes’. His belief was [only] based on what his Natural ‘senses’ confirmed. But notice what Jesus says later on …

> **JOHN 20:29** *Then Jesus told him, “Because you have seen me, you have believed; blessed are those who have not seen and yet have believed.”*

The greater ‘blessing’ or ‘benefit’ comes when you ‘believe’ without ‘signs’. But, in order to understand this fully, you need to understand what ‘signs’ are for. They are only, and specifically to satisfy the ‘natural senses’. Or, as the Apostle Paul uses, ‘flesh’.

Flesh from the Greek ‘sarx’ - *the sensuous nature of man*. And the New Testament was written for believers who Paul exhorts to ‘walk in the spirit’, and to disregard satisfying ‘the flesh’.

So because ‘signs’ are for those walking ‘in the flesh’, therefore the recorded ‘signs’ are *only* written to those ‘living in the flesh’ - specifically the Jews who had grownup under Torah/Law, which is totally ‘flesh orientated’, that *they* may “believe that Jesus is the Christ”

But they now, post cross, need to start leaving that ‘need’. It is just as Paul outlined …

> **1 COR 1:22** *Jews demand signs and Greeks look for wisdom,*

So ‘Jews’ demand ‘signs’, but the gospel Paul preached appeals to ‘the spirit’. Not the ‘natural’ [which needs signs], nor the ‘mind’ [Greeks stooped in philosophy]

Answer (score 0):

I would think the other miracles not recorded were simply to help people who were suffering and in need and at the sime perhaps increase the faith and belief of a specific smaller group who witnessed them.

Helping others and drawing people back to God was really the "primary" purpose of all the miracles. Many however were orchestrated in such a way that they could be used as "teaching aids" for wider discemination or to increase faith of very large groups (like Lazaruses resurrection). But others were simply becauser a sick person came to Jesus and needed to be healed.

Its like Jesus said:

> If any of you has a sheep and it falls into a pit on the Sabbath, will
> you not take hold of it and lift it out?

What was the purpose of the other miracles ? To lift the lost and broken sheep Jesus came across out of the pit :) That simple.